# Does Javascript have a conditional assignment like Ruby's ||= (Double pipe)

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

In Ruby you have something called a conditional assignment (`||=`). You can use it to assign values to variables if they have not already been defined or set. It is similar to saying this in Javascript:

```
if (typeof x == undefined) { x = 'value' }
```

In Ruby, to assign `'value` to `x` if it has not already been assigned, you would use `x ||= 'value`

Example of how it works:

```
x = 1
x ||= 2
return x    // Will return 1
```

Or:

```
x ||= 2
return x    // Will return 2
```

Is there any way to do this in Javascript without the significantly longer `if` statement?

---

**Solved:** @tede24 suggested the following

```
var x = x || newValue
```

The only way it is different to Ruby is that if `x` has been defined to `0`, i.e. `var x = 0`, the will set `x` to `newValue`

---

Comment: You should not use variables named `var`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't, just when I was typing the example quickly I accidentally used `var` instead of `x`

Comment: Please do not add solutions to questions. If an existing answer does not satisfy you, then write your own answer. If you have comments on someone else's answer, then add it as a comment on that answer.

Comment: Here's a really old thread on this topic: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/logical-assignment-operators. Slightly newer: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/is-much-needed.

Comment: By the way, `typeof x == undefined` is incorrect. It should be `typeof x == "undefined"`, with `undefined` in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var x = x || newValue;
```

This mean whenever x has something being evaluated as false (undefined, null, 0), it will assign the second value.

Comment: x == x || newValue;    // Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

Comment: No, `x` has not always been declared before (I edit my question, I realize I said "set" rather than "declared")

Comment: Sorry corrected a typo = instead of ==

Comment: It does, unless x is assigned `false` or `0`. In Ruby, it will not set `newValue` even if `x == false` or `x == 0`. Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjtvadym/)

Comment: Actually, Ruby will return `newValue` is `x == false`, however if it is `0` it will return `0`. [Check this](http://labs.codecademy.com/DLrb/3#:workspace)

Comment: Yes I stated 0 behavior in the answer. This is what js does. If you need to replicate ruby behavior you will need to use a function to make comparisons and return what you need

Comment: @tede24, Yes, it is stated in your answer, thanks!

Comment: @torazaburo the question states the variable might be not defined or not set. I agree if you know x is defined you shouldn't re define it, but if you don't know (this case) this is the way to go.

Comment: *If you need to replicate ruby behavior you will need to use a function to make comparisons and return what you need.* But that is what the question was asking you to do! I am confused. @Druzion appears to have accepted an answer because at least it explicitly states that it does not actually do what he asked for in his question?

Comment: @torazaburo It does exactly want I want it to do.

Comment: Then your question is framed incorrectly. You said "Is there any way to do **this**", where **this** is presumably the Ruby conditional assignment.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = typeof x !== 'undefined' ? x : newValue;
```

UPDATE  :  tede24  has better answer, i was just trying to learn - How to get rid of reference error, if used without var or already not declared

Comment: Yes, this does work, though @tede24 answer was more efficient. However, in @tede24's answer, if `x` has been assigned before it is reassigned using `var x = newValue`, whereas yours will just do `x = newValue`. So if using `var` to re-assign a variable is incorrect, then your answer it the best one here.

Comment: Well, what can I say :)

Comment: No, this answer is better. This is actually the code that Babel would generate for a default parameter.

Comment: @torazaburo I did specifically ask for an answer **without** the `if` statement though (read my question carefully), so this is **not** the best answer

Comment: The accepted answer is not equivalent to the Ruby you mention, because it re-assigns `x` if it has any falsy value, including 0, empty string, etc.